# What is all the stuff at the end of 9?

Tags: 9-2009

In the movie *9*, and yes this is a lead-in, you notice many strange things in concept. For instance the puppets having a soul are odd and even odder is the machinery that hunts them. So honestly I'm full of questions.

> At the end of the movie *9*, you notice many strange greenish glowing bacteria like substances that have exploded into the entire world. I imagine this things being the next evolution of the human race.

What exactly are these things? Do we not know? Is it one of those mysterious left for us to wonder, or do we know where they came from?

Comment: I enjoyed the movie, but personally I think it was obvious they got the whole story from the short film, the story was very thin.

Comment: Huh? I loved the post-apocalyptic environment... the plot was alright, nothing like the Lord of the Rings, but I loved it... plus the awesome trailer music... cue the cohed song....

Comment: no arguments about the environment, the art, everything visual. It was a beautiful film, just had a kinda weak plot is all.

Comment: Yeah, nothings perfect... tho. Wonder what it would be like with a great plot... cue cinematic music.

Comment: Too much characterization and too weak plot... the total opposite of a Philip K Dick novel.

Answer (score 12):

Indeed it was a fine a movie. The way I understood it, the "green energy" were the souls being released back into the world. Perhaps implying that it would be the seed of new life forms.

Comment: That's what I was assuming as well, but how does that work? Any in-universe info?

Comment: I don't believe its been mentioned. Then again, it's a Tim Burton movie (produced). Imagery has always been more important than technical details in those. But I think the film is based on a short story. Perhaps it has more explanations?

Answer (score 6):

I don't remember the exact wording, but I think that the reveal that it was bacteria came from the commentary track for that scene, not anything in-universe. And yes, it was supposed to be implied that all life, even bacteria, was wiped out during the cataclysmic war, and the green things were a new start for (non-mechanical) life at a microscopic level.

Answer (score 0):

So I just finished it , I felt that when the souls went up and started or restarted the rain , that each drip contained a spec of new life . I have had dreams(or nightmares) of a post apocolyptic earth ever since I snuck out of bed to see mad Max beyond thunderdome  when we first got HBO . My dreams always looked more like 9.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  I think the point of the question was what kind of life does the green stuff represent?  Can you add that to your post so it answers the question?  Please read [answer].